# .htaccess mod_rewrite changes page rendering

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

adding at my .htaccess this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /collection.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

(for changing: mydomain/collection.php?c=7&p=25 to mydomain/7/25)

all my pages are not rendered properly, and there are not images, it seems like if the base is changed (for example no css is applied), but on the console every file status is 200.
In the console I've got these messages (not really helpful for me):

- Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://mydomain/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css".
- Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://mydomain/css/lex.css".
- jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I've already used it in other websites but this is the first time I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rule below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /collection.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

Because you change the base path, you have to fix that, with:

```
<base href="/">
```

or

```
<base href="http://domain.com/">
```

in html `<header>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've already tried it and it doesn't change anything, I've also tried with RewriteBase / without success.

Comment: Yes, you also need to add -d and -f test, to avoid rewriting these files. I edit my code.